# Is there a way of spawning new threads with copies of existing data that have a non-static lifetime?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a problem that is similar to what is discussed in [Is there a succinct way to spawn new threads with copies of existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393874/is-there-a-succinct-way-to-spawn-new-threads-with-copies-of-existing-data). Unlike the linked question, I am trying to move an object with an associated lifetime into the new thread.

Intuitively, what I am trying to do is to copy *everything* that is necessary to continue the computation to the new thread and exit the old one. However, when trying to move cloned data (with a lifetime) to the new thread, I get the following error:

> error[E0759]: `data` has lifetime `'a` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement

I created a reproducible example based on the referenced question [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=af685c16e3c4fa6114d09546728d9f88). This is just to exemplify the problem. Here, the lifetimes could be removed easily but in my actual use-case the data I want to move to the thread is much more complex.

Is there an easy way of making this work with Rust?

Comment: remove your strange lifetime ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7526b6af5099c732234cefecbcfaa459

Comment: @Stargateur The playground example is just to illustrate the problem with lifetimes. In my actual use-case, the data I want to pass to the thread is much more complex. Sorry! Should've made this more clear in the question.

Comment: The whole point of using `Arc` is to remove the lifetime and make the object owned (aka `T: 'static`). If you still have a lifetime attached to it, it means that you didn't really "copy everything that is necessary to continue the computation". If your code compiled, the object the lifetime is attached to could be destroyed while the thread is still running. I'm afraid you'll need to provide more details to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Note that cloning doesn't help with references because `clone()` must return a value of the same type as the original. If the original value contains a reference (e.g. it's a type such as `struct Foo { x: String, y: &u32 }`), clone has no choice but to reproduce the same reference. If it cloned the underlying value and used a reference to the new value in the clone (e.g. if `Foo::clone()` created a new `u32` and referred to it in the `Foo` it returns), who would own that value and when would it be dropped?

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks! That makes sense! In my use-case I am building a python module with pyo3 which takes some functions (/callables) from Python. These have to be taken as a reference which have a non-static lifetime (see https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.14.1/pyo3/struct.PyAny.html). Is there be a way of moving the context to the new thread and dropping everything once the thread terminates?

Comment: I'll update the playground example to reflect this more accurately.

Comment: PyO3 is a good example of why what you're trying to do is forbidden. As I understand it, the `'py` lifetime represents the GIL being held. If you could move objects with that lifetime to a different threads, what's to stop you from releasing the GIL in the original thread? I am not familiar enough with PyO3 to help you, but I expect you need to either store your objects in the GIL-independent `PyAny` (and acquire the GIL again in the other thread when you need the data), or completely extract data from them to owned Rust objects (and just use them from the other thread).

Comment: To raise the probability of getting a good answer, please add a minimal example directly in the question (an additional playground link is of course fine as well), and make sure it includes an example of a PyO3 value that you want to move to the thread.

Comment: Reading over the pyo3 docs, I see that you can convert a `PyAny` reference to a concrete `PyObject` via `.to_object()`. Which the [doc says](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.14.1/pyo3/prelude/type.PyObject.html) is safe to pass among threads.  Why not do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A qualified answer to the question in the title is "yes", but we can't do it by copying non-static references. The reasons for this seeming limitation are sound. The way we can get the required data/objects into the thread closures is by passing ownership of them (or copies of them, or other concrete objects that represent them) to the closures.

It may not be immediately clear on how to do this with a complex library like `pyo3` since much of the API returns reference types to objects rather than concrete objects that can be passed as-is to other threads, but the library does provide ways to pass Python data/objects to other threads, which I'll cover in the second example below.

The `start()` function will need to put a `'static` bound on the closure type associated with its `data` parameter because within its body, `start()` is passing these closures on to other threads. The compiler is working to guarantee that the closures aren't holding on to references to anything that may evaporate if a thread runs longer than its parent, which is why it gripes without the `'static` guarantee.

```rust
fn start<'a>(data      : Vec<Arc<dyn Fn() -> f64 + Send + Sync + 'static>>,
             more_data : String) 
{
    for _ in 1..=4 {
        let cloned_data = data.clone();
        let cloned_more_data = more_data.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || foo(cloned_data, cloned_more_data));
    }
}
```

A `'static` bound is different than a `'static` lifetime applied to a reference (`data: 'static` vs. `&'static data`). In the case of a bound, it only means the type it's applied to doesn't contain any non-static references (if it even holds any references at all). **It's pretty common to see this bound applied to method parameters in threaded code.**

As this applies specifically to the `pyo3` problem space, we can avoid forming closures that contain non-static references by converting any such references to owned objects, then when the callback, running in another thread, needs to do something with them, it can acquire the GIL and cast them back to Python object references.

**More about this in the code comments below**. I took a [simple example](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3#using-python-from-rust) from the `pyo3` GitHub README and combined it with the code provided in the [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=af685c16e3c4fa6114d09546728d9f88).

Something to watch out for when applying this pattern is deadlock. The threads will need to acquire the GIL in order to use the Python objects they have access to. In the example, once the parent thread is done spawning new threads, it releases the GIL when it goes out of scope. The parent then waits for the child threads to complete by joining their handles.

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::sync::Arc;

use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::types::IntoPyDict;
use pyo3::types::PyDict;

type MyClosure<'a> = dyn Fn() -> f64 + Send + Sync + 'a;

fn main() -> Result<(), ()> 
{
    match Python::with_gil(|py| main_(py)
        .map_err(|e| e.print_and_set_sys_last_vars(py))) 
    {
        Ok(handles) => {
            for handle in handles {
                handle.join().unwrap();
            }},
        Err(e) => { println!("{:?}", e); },
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main_(py: Python) -> PyResult<Vec<JoinHandle<()>>> 
{
    let sys     = py.import("sys")?;
    let version = sys.get("version")?.extract::<String>()?;
    let locals  = [("os", py.import("os")?)].into_py_dict(py);
    let code    = "os.getenv('USER') or os.getenv('USERNAME') or 'Unknown'";
    let user    = py.eval(code, None, Some(&locals))?.extract::<String>()?;
    
    println!("Hello {}, I'm Python {}", user, version);
    
    // The thread will do something with the `locals` dictionary. In order to
    // pass this reference object to the thread, first convert it to a 
    // non-reference object.
    
    // Convert `locals` to `PyObject`.
    let locals_obj = locals.to_object(py);
    
    // Now we can move `locals_obj` into the thread without concern.
    let closure: Arc<MyClosure<'_>> = Arc::new(move || {
    
        // We can print out the PyObject which reveals it to be a tuple
        // containing a pointer value.
        println!("{:?}", locals_obj);
        
        // If we want to do anything with the `locals` object, we can cast it
        // back to a `PyDict` reference. We'll need to acquire the GIL first.
        Python::with_gil(|py| {
        
            // We have the GIL, cast the dict back to a PyDict reference.
            let py_dict = locals_obj.cast_as::<PyDict>(py).unwrap();
            
            // Printing it out reveals it to be a dictionary with the key `os`.
            println!("{:?}", py_dict);
        });
        1.
    });
    let data    = vec![closure];
    let more    = "Important data.".to_string();    
    let handles = start(data, more);
    Ok(handles)
}

fn start<'a>(data : Vec<Arc<MyClosure<'static>>>,
             more : String
            ) -> Vec<JoinHandle<()>>
{
    let mut handles = vec![];
    for _ in 1..=4 {
        let cloned_data = data.clone();
        let cloned_more = more.clone();
        
        let h = thread::spawn(move || foo(cloned_data, cloned_more));
        handles.push(h);
    }
    handles
}           

fn foo<'a>(data : Vec<Arc<MyClosure<'a>>>,
           more : String)
{
    for closure in data {
        closure();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello todd, I'm Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0]
Py(0x7f3329ccdd40)
Py(0x7f3329ccdd40)
Py(0x7f3329ccdd40)
{'os': <module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py'>}
{'os': <module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py'>}
{'os': <module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py'>}
Py(0x7f3329ccdd40)
{'os': <module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py'>}
```

Something to consider: you may be able to minimize, or eliminate, the need to pass Python objects to the threads by extracting all the information needed from them into Rust objects and passing those to threads instead.

Comment: The problem with this is that it won't work for the OP, because they don't want `start()` to compile in isolation, but to be able to invoke it with a closure that captures a non-static lifetime (the `'py` lifetime that represents the Python GIL being held).

Comment: I believe this may actually be the solution to the problem after changes are made to eliminate the non-static references the closure holds by using `.to_object()` on the `PyAny` references. @user4815162342